# Loyalty Program: Halal or Haram?

Tags: sharia, riba, islamic-scholar

Salam!
Today, I came across a question on ask.ghamdi.org forum. I'm curious to know the answer. The question is:

The city in which I’m currently living in has loyalty program where if I buy a member card (with money), I receive a fixed percentage (10%) of amount I spent on buying the member card, each month. The fixed percentage is in the form of points that I can spend only on specific vendors.

When I want to cancel the membership, The program deducts the same percentage (10%) of amount and returned the remaining amount.

For example:

I bought the membership with 100$.

Now each month I receive 10% of 100$ i.e. 10 points (1 point = 1 $)

When I want to cancel, the program deducts 10% of 100$ and give me 90$

My question is about the 10% I’m receiving each month: Is it SOOD?

Original source: https://ask.ghamidi.org/forums/discussion/83015/

Comment: On what basis would this be haram? What happens in this occurrence that makes you think something is haram?

Comment: the 10% I'm receiving without any work

Comment: The construct is highly suspicions. Riba or not, no one can pay you 10% *monthly*. My guess is that the prices you have to pay at those shops are highly exaggerated. Stay away from this.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaykum!
It looks similar to common banking system. You give them a "loan" and get fixed benefit every year or month. But in this case in Bonuses.

**Why it is haram?**

Because, you get fixed percentage. This is not an investment, it's a loan. You don't have risk of loosing benefit. And you can withdraw your money whenever you want. So, does it look exactly like banking system? Yes! **It is a Riba!**

0, believers, consciously revere Allah, and give up what is still due to you from the Riba, if you are true believers.”
**Al-Quran 2/278**

And do not bestow a favour in the expectation of receiving more in return.
**Al-Quran 74/6**

O you who believe! (Do) not eat Riba doubled, re-doubled. And consciously revere Allah so that you may (be) successful. **Surah Ale ‘Imran, verses 130 (Quran 3/130)**

O you who have believed, spend from the good things which you have earned and from that which We have produced for you from the earth. And do not aim toward the defective therefrom, spending [from that] while you would not take it [yourself] except with closed eyes. And know that Allah is Free of need and Praiseworthy.
**[Al-Quran 2/267]**

For more information you can visit https://quranicteachings.org/riba-in-the-quran/